# Better way to manipulate data using AWK and SED

Tags: awk, sed, posix, gnu

I am wondering if somebody could help me re-write this in a more sensible and smarter way?

```
sed -e '1d; $d' <someinputfile> |
awk -F"\t" '{split($2,a,/-/); print $1","a[1]","a[2]","$3","$4","$5","$6}' |
sed -e "s/,/\",\"/g" |
sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' |
sed -e $'1i\\\"field_one","field_two","field_three","field_four","field_five","field_six","field_seven"'
```

It is possible to write the correct output already with awk and I assume there are much better ways to write this.

Shorter way? More efficient way? More correct way? POSIX compliant? GNU compliant?

If you can help please also try to explain the changes as I really want to understand "how" and "what is what" :)

Thanks!

What it does is:

1. Deletes first and last lines
2. Splits the second field based on separator - and prints it (here it should be possible to print the right format right away?)
3. Change , to "," from the previous awk print
4. Add " around all lines
5. Add a new header

If somebody wants to play with inputfile here is an example:

```
START   9       1997-07-27T13:37:01Z
X1      24087-27        Axgma8PYjc1yRJlUr41688  1997-07-27T13:09:00Z    9876    OK
X1      642-68  6nwPtLQTqAAKufH3ejoEeg  1997-07-27T14:31:00Z    9876    OK
X1      642-31  qfKH99UnxZTcp2AN8NNB21  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      642-24  PouJBByqUJkqhKHBynUesD  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      642-30  J7t2sJKKtcxWJr18I84A46  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      642-29  g7hPkNpUywvk6FvGqgpHsx  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      642-26  W2KM24xvmy0Q8cLV950tXq  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      642-25  dqu8jB5tUthIKevNAQXgld  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      753-32  Gh0kZkIJr8j6FSYljbpyyy  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      753-23  Jvl8LMh6SDHfgvLfJIHi5l  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      753-28  IZ83996cthjhZGYcAk97iJ  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      753-22  YJwokU0Dq6xiydkf3EDyxl  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      753-36  OZHOMirRKjA3LcXTbPJL31  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      753-34  LvMgT6ed1b1e3uwasGi48G  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9877    OK
X1      753-35  VJk4x8sTG1BJTnZYvgu6px  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9876    OK
X1      663-27  mkZXgTHKBjmAplrDeoQZXo  1997-07-27T16:15:00Z    9875    ERR
X1              f1K1PzQ9sp2QAv1AX0Zix4  1997-07-27T16:27:00Z    9875    ERR
DONE     69      3QXFXKQAFRSZXJLJ6JZ9NWMXR00B1V1J1FUMBQAA9DQSRCTZF8JXAWWSGHSDIPQ9
```

Thanks!

PS: Since I'm not sure if you will get the same output on your computer here is how it correctly looks for me when I run it and how I want it:

```
"field_one","field_two","field_three","field_four","field_five","field_six","field_seven"
"X1","24087","27","Axgma8PYjc1yRJlUr41688","1997-07-27T13:09:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","68","6nwPtLQTqAAKufH3ejoEeg","1997-07-27T14:31:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","31","qfKH99UnxZTcp2AN8NNB21","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","24","PouJBByqUJkqhKHBynUesD","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","30","J7t2sJKKtcxWJr18I84A46","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","29","g7hPkNpUywvk6FvGqgpHsx","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","26","W2KM24xvmy0Q8cLV950tXq","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","25","dqu8jB5tUthIKevNAQXgld","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","32","Gh0kZkIJr8j6FSYljbpyyy","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","23","Jvl8LMh6SDHfgvLfJIHi5l","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","28","IZ83996cthjhZGYcAk97iJ","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","22","YJwokU0Dq6xiydkf3EDyxl","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","36","OZHOMirRKjA3LcXTbPJL31","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","34","LvMgT6ed1b1e3uwasGi48G","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9877","OK"
"X1","753","35","VJk4x8sTG1BJTnZYvgu6px","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","663","27","mkZXgTHKBjmAplrDeoQZXo","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9875","ERR"
"X1","","","f1K1PzQ9sp2QAv1AX0Zix4","1997-07-27T16:27:00Z","9875","ERR"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS="\t"
        OFS="\",\""                 # define output field delimiter as <doublequote> <comma> <doublequote>

        # print header
        print "\"field_one","field_two","field_three","field_four","field_five","field_six","field_seven\""
      }

FNR>1 { if (prev) print prev
        split($2,a,"-")

        # reformat current line and save in variable "prev", to be printed on next pass; add <doublequote> on ends
        prev= "\"" $1 OFS a[1] OFS a[2] OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5 OFS $6 "\""
      }
' input.dat
```

This generates:

```
"field_one","field_two","field_three","field_four","field_five","field_six","field_seven"
"X1","24087","27","Axgma8PYjc1yRJlUr41688","1997-07-27T13:09:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","68","6nwPtLQTqAAKufH3ejoEeg","1997-07-27T14:31:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","31","qfKH99UnxZTcp2AN8NNB21","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","24","PouJBByqUJkqhKHBynUesD","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","30","J7t2sJKKtcxWJr18I84A46","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","29","g7hPkNpUywvk6FvGqgpHsx","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","26","W2KM24xvmy0Q8cLV950tXq","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","25","dqu8jB5tUthIKevNAQXgld","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","32","Gh0kZkIJr8j6FSYljbpyyy","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","23","Jvl8LMh6SDHfgvLfJIHi5l","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","28","IZ83996cthjhZGYcAk97iJ","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","22","YJwokU0Dq6xiydkf3EDyxl","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","36","OZHOMirRKjA3LcXTbPJL31","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","34","LvMgT6ed1b1e3uwasGi48G","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9877","OK"
"X1","753","35","VJk4x8sTG1BJTnZYvgu6px","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","663","27","mkZXgTHKBjmAplrDeoQZXo","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9875","ERR"
"X1","","","f1K1PzQ9sp2QAv1AX0Zix4","1997-07-27T16:27:00Z","9875","ERR"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would rework this part of your code

```
awk -F"\t" '{split($2,a,/-/); print $1","a[1]","a[2]","$3","$4","$5","$6}' | sed -e "s/,/\",\"/g" | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' | sed -e $'1i\\\"field_one","field_two","field_three","field_four","field_five","field_six","field_seven"'
```

following way, 1st step: use `","` rather than `,` and then changing it, i.e.

```
awk -F"\t" '{split($2,a,/-/); print $1"\",\""a[1]"\",\""a[2]"\",\""$3"\",\""$4"\",\""$5"\",\""$6}' | sed 's/^/"/;s/$/"/' | sed -e $'1i\\\"field_one","field_two","field_three","field_four","field_five","field_six","field_seven"'
```

2nd step: add leading `"` and trailing `"` in `print` i.e.

```
awk -F"\t" '{split($2,a,/-/); print "\""$1"\",\""a[1]"\",\""a[2]"\",\""$3"\",\""$4"\",\""$5"\",\""$6"\""}' | sed -e $'1i\\\"field_one","field_two","field_three","field_four","field_five","field_six","field_seven"'
```

3rd step: use `BEGIN` to `print` header i.e.

```
awk -F"\t" 'BEGIN{print "\"field_one\",\"field_two\",\"field_three\",\"field_four\",\"field_five\",\"field_six\",\"field_seven\""}{split($2,a,/-/); print "\""$1"\",\""a[1]"\",\""a[2]"\",\""$3"\",\""$4"\",\""$5"\",\""$6"\""}'
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
sed -E 's/\t/\\t/g' file
START\t9\t1997-07-27T13:37:01Z
X1\t24087-27\tAxgma8PYjc1yRJlUr41688\t1997-07-27T13:09:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t642-68\t6nwPtLQTqAAKufH3ejoEeg\t1997-07-27T14:31:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t642-31\tqfKH99UnxZTcp2AN8NNB21\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t642-24\tPouJBByqUJkqhKHBynUesD\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t642-30\tJ7t2sJKKtcxWJr18I84A46\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t642-29\tg7hPkNpUywvk6FvGqgpHsx\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t642-26\tW2KM24xvmy0Q8cLV950tXq\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t642-25\tdqu8jB5tUthIKevNAQXgld\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t753-32\tGh0kZkIJr8j6FSYljbpyyy\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t753-23\tJvl8LMh6SDHfgvLfJIHi5l\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t753-28\tIZ83996cthjhZGYcAk97iJ\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t753-22\tYJwokU0Dq6xiydkf3EDyxl\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t753-36\tOZHOMirRKjA3LcXTbPJL31\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t753-34\tLvMgT6ed1b1e3uwasGi48G\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9877\tOK
X1\t753-35\tVJk4x8sTG1BJTnZYvgu6px\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9876\tOK
X1\t663-27\tmkZXgTHKBjmAplrDeoQZXo\t1997-07-27T16:15:00Z\t9875\tERR
X1\t\tf1K1PzQ9sp2QAv1AX0Zix4\t1997-07-27T16:27:00Z\t9875\tERR
DONE\t69\t3QXFXKQAFRSZXJLJ6JZ9NWMXR00B1V1J1FUMBQAA9DQSRCTZF8JXAWWSGHSDIPQ9
```

It is a very good idea to use a proper CSV parser to deal with issues like this.

Ruby is ubiquitous and has a very lightweight but capable CSV parser included in the distribution.

Here is a ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
data=CSV.parse($<.read, **{:col_sep=>"\t"})
d2=CSV::Table.new([], headers:["field_one","field_two","field_three","field_four","field_five","field_six","field_seven"])
data[1...-1].each { |r| 
    r_=[]
    r.each_with_index { |e,i|
        if i == 1 
            e && e[/-/] ? (r_.concat e.split(/-/,2)) : (r_.concat ["",""])
        else
            r_ << e
        end
    }
    d2 << r_ }
puts d2.to_csv(**{:force_quotes=>true})
' file
```

Prints:

```
"field_one","field_two","field_three","field_four","field_five","field_six","field_seven"
"X1","24087","27","Axgma8PYjc1yRJlUr41688","1997-07-27T13:09:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","68","6nwPtLQTqAAKufH3ejoEeg","1997-07-27T14:31:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","31","qfKH99UnxZTcp2AN8NNB21","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","24","PouJBByqUJkqhKHBynUesD","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","30","J7t2sJKKtcxWJr18I84A46","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","29","g7hPkNpUywvk6FvGqgpHsx","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","26","W2KM24xvmy0Q8cLV950tXq","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","25","dqu8jB5tUthIKevNAQXgld","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","32","Gh0kZkIJr8j6FSYljbpyyy","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","23","Jvl8LMh6SDHfgvLfJIHi5l","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","28","IZ83996cthjhZGYcAk97iJ","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","22","YJwokU0Dq6xiydkf3EDyxl","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","36","OZHOMirRKjA3LcXTbPJL31","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","34","LvMgT6ed1b1e3uwasGi48G","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9877","OK"
"X1","753","35","VJk4x8sTG1BJTnZYvgu6px","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","663","27","mkZXgTHKBjmAplrDeoQZXo","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9875","ERR"
"X1","","","f1K1PzQ9sp2QAv1AX0Zix4","1997-07-27T16:27:00Z","9875","ERR"
```

Answer (score 1):

not as elegant of a solution as i hoped for, but it got the job done -

instead of hard-coding in verbal names for fields, it would simple compute the required header row on the fly based on actual input, which also accounts for the anticipated split of field 2

```
 gnice gcat sample.txt \
                        \
 | mawk2 'function trim(_) { return \
                         \
       substr("",gsub("^[,\42]*|[,\42]*$","\42",_))_ 

  } BEGIN {  FS =   "[ \11]+"
            OFS = "\42\54\42" 
  } NR==2 { 
            for(_=NF+!_;_;_—) { 
               ___=(_)(OFS)___
            }
            printf("%*s\n",gsub("[0-9]+[^0-9]+",\
                   "field_&",___)~"",trim(___)) 

  } !/^(START|DONE)/ {
      
     printf("\42%.0s%s\42\n",$1=$(($0=\
             $(sub("[-]"," ",$2)<""))~""),$0) } ' | lgp3 3 

"field_1","field_2","field_3","field_4","field_5","field_6","field_7"
"X1","24087","27","Axgma8PYjc1yRJlUr41688","1997-07-27T13:09:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","68","6nwPtLQTqAAKufH3ejoEeg","1997-07-27T14:31:00Z","9876","OK"

"X1","642","31","qfKH99UnxZTcp2AN8NNB21","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","24","PouJBByqUJkqhKHBynUesD","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","30","J7t2sJKKtcxWJr18I84A46","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"

"X1","642","29","g7hPkNpUywvk6FvGqgpHsx","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","26","W2KM24xvmy0Q8cLV950tXq","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","642","25","dqu8jB5tUthIKevNAQXgld","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"

"X1","753","32","Gh0kZkIJr8j6FSYljbpyyy","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","23","Jvl8LMh6SDHfgvLfJIHi5l","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","28","IZ83996cthjhZGYcAk97iJ","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"

"X1","753","22","YJwokU0Dq6xiydkf3EDyxl","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","36","OZHOMirRKjA3LcXTbPJL31","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","753","34","LvMgT6ed1b1e3uwasGi48G","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9877","OK"

"X1","753","35","VJk4x8sTG1BJTnZYvgu6px","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9876","OK"
"X1","663","27","mkZXgTHKBjmAplrDeoQZXo","1997-07-27T16:15:00Z","9875","ERR"
"X1","f1K1PzQ9sp2QAv1AX0Zix4","1997-07-27T16:27:00Z","9875","ERR"
```